# Invoking the IDL pre-processor

Tags: c, linux, chat, idl, data-distribution-service

I am working on a linux 4.20 and ubuntu 15.10 virtual machine and my host is windows 7. I am trying to implement a simple chat message example using Data Distribution Service (DDS) protocol provided by Prismtech (Community Edition).

I came across a tutorial where I have to invoke the Chat.idl. Below there is the code in the file, which contains body for interconnection between a server and a client.

```
module Chat {
    const long MAX_NAME = 32;
    typedef string<MAX_NAME> nameType;
    struct ChatMessage {
    long userID; // owner of message
    long index; // message number
    string content; // message body
    };

    #pragma keylist ChatMessage userID
    struct NameService {
    long userID; // unique user identification
    nameType name; // name of the user
    };

    #pragma keylist NameService userID
    struct NamedMessage {
    long userID;   //unique user identification
    nameType userName  //user name
    long index;     //message number
    string content; //message body
    };
    #pragma keylist NamedMessage userID
    };
```

to invoke this i am supposed to type in "idlpp -S -l c Chat.idl" in my command-line (terminal). Below is my output from the terminal showing "IDL parser error: opening file chat.idl".

```
    -virtual-machine:~/HDE/x86.linux$ idlpp
    Usage: idlpp [-c preprocessor-path] [-b ORB-template-path]
   [-n <include-suffix>] [-I path] [-D macro[=definition]] [-S | -C] 
   [-l (c | c++ | cpp | isocpp | isoc++ | cs | java)] [-j [old]:<new>] [-d directory] [-i] 
   [-P dll_macro_name[,<h-file>]] [-o (dds-types | custom-psm | no-equality)] <filename>

    akhil@akhil-virtual-machine:~/HDE/x86.linux$ idlpp  -S -l c chat.idl
    IDL parser error: opening file chat.idl
```

Comment: The error message, "IDL parser error: opening file chat.idl", indicates that the IDL file is not accessible (either not in the current directory, or not readable). Check that the IDL file exists in the current directory and has suitable permissions. [ try "ls -l" ]  Further, you indicate that the file is named Chat.idl, but are passing chat.idl on the command line.

Comment: Thank you @CTucker  I was mislead with the description in the file that I was going through. You were right, I am using another IDL file.....